# Image View is Causing Awkward Hang?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimageview, notifications

I've been working on this for a couple days now (off & on) and I'm not *exactly* sure why this isn't working, so I'm askin you pros at SOF for some insight.

## NewsItem.m

On my first view controller, I'm reading from a JSON feed which has 10+ items. Each item is represented by a `NewsItem` view which allows for a title, body copy, and a small image. The `UIImageView` has an `IBOutlet` called **imageView**. I'm loading the image for my **imageView** asynchronously. When the image is loaded, I'm dispatching a notification called **IMAGE_LOADED**. This notification is only picked up on the the **NewsItemArticle**

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]];
    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.imageView setAlpha:0.0];
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
        [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [self.imageView setAlpha:1.0];
        }];

        if(self)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IMAGE_LOADED object:self];
    });
});
```

## NewsItemArticle.m

When a user taps on a **NewsItemView** then I load a new controller which is a scroll view of several **NewsItemArticle** views inside a scrollview. A **NewsItemArticle** will listen for **IMAGE_LOADED** and if it is decided the current notification has an image for this particular article, it will use the same image for it's own reference like so:

```
- (void)handleImageLoaded:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if([note.object isEqual:self.cell]) {
        // this next line is hanging the app. not sure why.
        [self.imageView setImage:self.cell.image];
        [self.activityViewIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

So essentially:

- I'm using an asynchronous load on my first image reference
- I'm using notifications to let other parts of the app know and image was loaded
- The app hangs when the existing image is reference to a second `UIImageView`

If I comment out the *suspect* line, the app never hangs. As it its, my app hangs until all the images are loaded. My thoughts are:

1. This is a network threading conflict (not likely)
2. This is a GPU threading conflict (perhaps during a resize to the container view's size?)

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Is the notification posted from the background thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lazy loading of table view images there are few good options available. Can make use of them in your design to save time and avoid efforts to reinvent the wheel.

1. Apple lazy loading code --[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

2. SDWebImage --[link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

SDWebImage will provide you a completion handler/block where you can use the notification mechanism to notify other modules of your application.

Cheers!
Amar.

Comment: These images aren't in a table though, they are in a scroll view. The image is already loaded in the other view controller too so I'm not sure why this is necessary.

Comment: SDWebImage will work with UIImageView placed in any container, even UIScrollView. It will download images without affecting the main thread. Using this will provide you caching as well, to some extent.

Comment: I had seen this code around SOF during my research but I had tried another form of asynchronous loading and for whatever reason, your first option is the one that works for me.